# Searching a list using multiple threads and find element (without using parallel streams)

Tags: java, multithreading, performance, parallel-processing, java-threads

I have a method

```
public boolean contains(int valueToFind, List<Integer> list) {
//
}
```

How can I split the array into x chunks? and have a new thread for searching every chunk looking for the value. If the method returns true, I would like to stop the other threads from searching.

I see there are lots of examples for simply splitting work between threads, but how I do structure it so that once one thread returns true, all threads and return that as the answer?

I do not want to use parallel streams for this reason (from [source](https://dzone.com/articles/think-twice-using-java-8)):

> If you do, please look at the previous example again. There is a big
> error. Do you see it? The problem is that all parallel streams use
> common fork-join thread pool, and if you submit a long-running task,
> you effectively block all threads in the pool. Consequently, you block
> all other tasks that are using parallel streams. Imagine a servlet
> environment, when one request calls getStockInfo() and another one
> countPrimes(). One will block the other one even though each of them
> requires different resources. What's worse, you can not specify thread
> pool for parallel streams; the whole class loader has to use the same
> one.

Comment: I think you dont understand the problem. You dont want that "all threads return". You basically ignore all the other threads. But note: unless this is for learning purposes, you should just go with the streams solution given to you. And I hope you understand that your list needs to be really large in order to gain a "speedup" by using multiple threads.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the built-in `Stream` API:

```
//For a List
public boolean contains(int valueToFind, List<Integer> list) {
   return list.parallelStream().anyMatch(Integer.valueOf(valueToFind)::equals);
}

//For an array
public boolean contains(int valueToFind, int[] arr){
   return Arrays.stream(arr).parallel().anyMatch(x -> x == valueToFind);
}
```

[Executing Streams in Parallel](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/streams/parallelism.html#executing_streams_in_parallel):

> You can execute streams in serial or in parallel. When a stream executes in parallel, the Java runtime partitions the stream into multiple substreams. Aggregate operations iterate over and process these substreams in parallel and then combine the results.
>
> When you create a stream, it is always a serial stream unless otherwise specified. To create a parallel stream, invoke the operation [Collection.parallelStream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#parallelStream--).