# Using Callable and ExecutorCompletionService, future.cancel() does not work

Tags: java, multithreading, parallel-processing, executorservice, callable

I am using a bunch of callables to search a list in individual chunks, once one returns true, I want to cancel all the other running callables. future.cancel is not cancelling them

My NumberFinder

```
    public class NumberFinderImpl implements NumberFinder {
  // how many threads the exucutor will use to start the callables
  private final int NUMBER_THREADS = 20;
  // the amount of elements in the array we will search in each callable chunk
  private final int CHUNK_ARRAY_SIZE = 5;

  @Override
  public boolean contains(int valueToFind, List<CustomNumberEntity> arrayToSearch) {
    long startTime = System.nanoTime();
    ExecutorService WORKER_THREAD_POOL = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(NUMBER_THREADS);
    CompletionService<Boolean> completionService =
        new ExecutorCompletionService<>(WORKER_THREAD_POOL);
    int numberOfChunksNeeded = (int) Math.ceil(arrayToSearch.size() / CHUNK_ARRAY_SIZE);
    // get a callable for each chunk search
    List<Callable<Boolean>> callablesForEachChunkSearch =
        getCallablesForEachChunk(
            CHUNK_ARRAY_SIZE, numberOfChunksNeeded, valueToFind, arrayToSearch);
    // start the callables and collect the futures
    List<Future<Boolean>> futuresForCallables =
        callablesForEachChunkSearch
            .stream()
            .map(completionService::submit)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
    for (int j = 0; j < futuresForCallables.size(); j++) {
      try {
        // take().get() is blocking
        // so if a callable is not done yet
        // it will wait until it is before proceeding
        Boolean chunkResult = completionService.take().get();
        if (chunkResult) {
          long endTime = System.nanoTime();
          long timeTaken = endTime - startTime;
          // TimeUnit
          long timeInSeconds = TimeUnit.SECONDS.convert(timeTaken, TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS);
          System.out.println("Search time in seconds" + timeInSeconds);
          for (Future<Boolean> future : futuresForCallables) {
            // cancel all the other running callables
            future.cancel(true);
          }
          return true;
        }
      } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      } catch (ExecutionException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
    }
    for (Future<Boolean> future : futuresForCallables) {
      // cancel all the other running callables
      future.cancel(true);
    }
    long endTime = System.nanoTime();
    long timeTaken = endTime - startTime;
    // TimeUnit
    long timeInSeconds = TimeUnit.SECONDS.convert(timeTaken, TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS);
    System.out.println("Search time in seconds" + timeInSeconds);
    return false;
  }

  // get a list of callables that each search a certain chunk of the array
  private List<Callable<Boolean>> getCallablesForEachChunk(
      int chunkArraySize,
      int numberOfChunksNeeded,
      int valueToFind,
      List<CustomNumberEntity> arrayToSearch) {
    List<Callable<Boolean>> callableList = new ArrayList<>(numberOfChunksNeeded);
    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfChunksNeeded; i++) {
      int startPosForCallable = 0;
      if (i > 0) {
        startPosForCallable = i * chunkArraySize;
      }
      // dont let end pos go out of bounds
      // if the chunk extends past the size, just set endPos as the end of the array
      int endPosForCallable =
          Math.min(startPosForCallable + chunkArraySize - 1, arrayToSearch.size());
      Callable<Boolean> callableSearch =
          new NumberFinderCallable(
              arrayToSearch, valueToFind, startPosForCallable, endPosForCallable);
      callableList.add(callableSearch);
    }
    return callableList;
  }
```

My callable that does the searching

```
    public class NumberFinderCallable implements Callable<Boolean> {

  private List<CustomNumberEntity> arrayToSearch;
  private int startPos;
  private int endPos;
  private int valueToSearchFor;

  public NumberFinderCallable(
      List<CustomNumberEntity> arrayToSearch, int valueToSearchFor, int startPos, int endPos) {
    this.arrayToSearch = arrayToSearch;
    this.startPos = startPos;
    this.endPos = endPos;
    this.valueToSearchFor = valueToSearchFor;
  }

  @Override
  public Boolean call() {
    System.out.println(
        "Callable started, searching the chunk of array with start pos "
            + startPos
            + " and end pos "
            + endPos);
    for (int i = startPos; i <= endPos; i++) {
      System.out.println(
          "Callable is comparing a number in pos "
              + i
              + " in the chunk with star pos "
              + +startPos
              + " and end pos "
              + endPos);
      if (FastestComparator.compare(valueToSearchFor, arrayToSearch.get(i)) == 0) {
        System.out.println("element found in pos " + i + ". Returning true");
        return true;
      }
    }
    return false;
  }
}
```

I can see from the logs even after a true result is found and all the futures are cancelled that the threads are still going

Answer (score 1):

Based on your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66140475/searching-a-list-using-multiple-threads-without-using-parallel-streams-and-fin) you have made it clear that you are trying to parallelize this `contains` method because of performance reasons and not for learning about the API. However, IMO you have made the *mistake* of assuming that this method actually needs to be optimized.

I have made an *ad hoc* test for a list with `100000000` (100 million) elements, and for the worst-case scenario *i.e.,* trying to find an element that does not exist in the list. For the sequential `contain` method

```
list.contains(Integer.MAX_VALUE)
```

it took in average approximately:

```
0.25 seconds
```

And the parallel version using streams:

```
list.parallelStream().anyMatch(i -> i.equals(Integer.MAX_VALUE))
```

it took in average approximately:

```
 0.19 seconds
```

A speedup of `1.32x` in a 4 core machine. I highly doubt it that one will achieve *a lot more* than that. Not to mention the maintainability and readability of:

```
list.parallelStream().anyMatch(i -> i.equals(Integer.MAX_VALUE))
```

versus a potential parallel solution using explicitly executors and so on.

If the `contain` method is that important performance-wise, and one does not have duplicated elements in the list, one should consider using a `HashSet` for a constant complexity time `contain` method.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of [ExecutorService](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html)

```
ExecutorService WORKER_THREAD_POOL = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(NUMBER_THREADS);
```

Use [ThreadPoolExecutor](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html)

```
ThreadPoolExecutor WORKER_THREAD_POOL = (ThreadPoolExecutor) Executors.newFixedThreadPool(NUMBER_THREADS);
```

Then do a [purge()](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html#purge()) to release threads of cancelled futures, e.g.

```
future.cancel(true);
WORKER_THREAD_POOL.purge();
```